# How to search through an array and check for a condition in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, methods

I have an array of both new cars and used cars. I want to search through the array for the cars who have the color green. The method `printAllCarsOfColor(String color)` will return a string which displays the information of all cars of a color given as argument. I have tried but no luck.

I have Car class which is the superclass and `NewCar` and `UsedCar` that are subclasses. Only `NewCar` class has the `Color` method. I can't figure out how to print out the cars that are only green.I understand that the method `Color` is not defined for `Car` class.

Looking for some help. Thanks!

My code:

```
public class CarDearlerShip
{
   private Car[] aCar;
   private int count;
   private int car;
  
   public CarDearlerShip()
   {
     aCar = new Car[80];
      count = 0;
      car = 0;  
   }
  
   
   public void addNewCar(String model, int year, int price, String color)
   {
      aCar[count] = new NewCar(model, year, price, color);
      count++;
   }   
   
   public void addUsedCar(String model, int year, int price, boolean rusty)
   {
      aCar[count] = new UsedCar(model, year, price, rusty);
      count++;
   } 
   
   public String printReport()
   {
      String report = "---------------------------------------------\n";
      report += "The list of availabel cars:\n\n";
      
     for (int car = 0; car < count; car++)
      report += aCar[car].toString() + "\n";
      //System.out.println(report);
    return report;
      
   }
   
  public String printAllCarsWithSellingPriceBelow(int price) 
   {
      String printCars = "---------------------------------------------\n";
      printCars += "The price for these cars are: \n\n";
      
      for (int car = 0; car < count; car++)
      {
          if (aCar[car].aPrice < 1000); // The argument for the selling price
          printCars +=aCar[car].getPrice();
      }
         return printCars;       
   
   }
   
   public String printAllCarsOfColor(String color)
   {
      String printColor = "---------------------------------------------\n";
      printColor += "The color : \n\n";
      
      
      for (int car = 0; car < count; car++)
      {
         if (aCar[car].Color()==color);
         printColor +=aCar[car];
         
      }
      return printColor;      
   
   }
}

The Test Class
    
public class TestDealer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CarDearlerShip dealer= new CarDearlerShip();
        dealer.addNewCar("GM Buick Century", 2004, 200000, "Silver");
        dealer.addUsedCar("Toyota Corolla", 1999, 9000, true);
        dealer.addNewCar("Honda Civic", 2004, 500, "Green");
        dealer.addNewCar("BMW 320i", 2004, 35000, "Black");
        dealer.addUsedCar("Toyota Sienna", 2000, 11000, false);
        
            System.out.println(dealer.printReport());
            System.out.println("**********************************");
        
        //System.out.println(dealer.printAllCarsWithSellingPriceBelow(1000));
            
            System.out.println("****************************************");

        System.out.println(dealer.printAllCarsOfColor("Green"));
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Share your `Car`, `UsedCar` and `NewCar` source?

Comment: Looks like a typo: `if (aCar[car].Color()==color);` shouldn't have the semi-colon (`;`) after it.  And you should use `.equals` for Strings.

Comment: I would think that color should be a property of Car rather than NewCar, which would make things much easier.

Answer (score 1):

When you are comparing the output of the Color method that your car has you need to be using the built in java.lang.String method .equals().

In your code you have: `if(aCar[car].Color()==color){`

But it needs to be `if(aCar[car].Color().equals(color)){`

Basically the compiler is never going to understand what you are saying because the String variable "Color" is just a pointer to a space in your computer's memory where it is storing the value "green." So when you compare "green" to that pointer they will never be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nick. I understand my mistake now. However, when I try to run the program, I get the following error below:

The method Color() is undefined for the type Car

Comment: Yes. In your NewCar/UsedCar class you need to create a getColor method. Or you can call it Color like you have it. That method should take the instance variable color that you are storing when you create a new car and return it. Then your program should work fine

Comment: Should look something like this in your NewCar/UsedCar class. public String getColor(){ return this.color; }

Comment: I completely agree @NomadMaker. I have tested your suggestion and it works. 

However, I'm doing a class project and in the details it mentions as follows:

the class Car should have a constructor Car(String model, int year, int price), 

class NewCar has the constructor NewCar(String model, int year, int price, String color), 

class UsedCar has the constructor UsedCar(String model, int year, int price, boolean rusty)

I wondering if there is another way of doing it with the requirements mentioned in the description.

Comment: Look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/chptr-one/691b4a9a8491b546dd6641655dd64946). This is bad, but it is possible. I think your task should not be solved by inheritance. Any car has a color and any car can be rusty, so these fields must be inside the car class. Then there is no point to extend class Car.